# Vue3, leaflet and search box - Uncaught TypeError: L.Control.Search.callJsonp is not a function

Tags: leaflet, vuejs3

I am trying to implement a search to leaflet 1.9.3 in vue3

This is code

```
import L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import 'leaflet-search/dist/leaflet-search.min.css';
import 'leaflet-search';

export default ({
  data() {
    return {
      zoom: 6,
      point: [],
      baseLayer: null,
      map: null,
    }
  },

mounted() {
  this.map = L.map('map').setView([-0.9085086842426627, 118.1511063353415], 5)
  this.baseLayer = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>',
    maxZoom: 18
  }).addTo(this.map);
 

  new L.Control.Search({
    url: 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&q={s}',
    jsonpParam: 'json_callback',
    propertyName: 'display_name',
    propertyLoc: ['lat', 'lon'],
    marker: L.circleMarker([0, 0], { radius: 30 }),
    autoCollapse: true,
    autoType: false,
    minLength: 2
  }).addTo(this.map);
}
```

and this code give me error

```
search?format=json&q=[object%20Object]&json_callback=L.Control.Search.callJsonp:1 Uncaught TypeError: L.Control.Search.callJsonp is not a function
```

Error appears when I start to use the search box. Development environment is localhost.

Comment: Do you mind sharing the entire code of that file?

Comment: look now, i added more code

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's related to an [issue](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search/issues/321). It's also doing the same on the demo [OSM project](https://opengeo.tech/maps/leaflet-search/examples/geocoding-nominatim.html).